# DotNetNuke "Password Expiry Reminder" does not work

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

I set the Password Expiry Reminder to 14 or XX days and clicked update.  Then I looked at it again it showed default values 7 days.
It never update the Password Expiry Reminder (in days) field, Is there bug in DNN.

I tried changing it to a number of days less than 7 and it doesn't set that either.

Could you please let me know what should I do? Please

Thanks and regards
Mohsin JK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this in DotNetNuke 5.6.1. In fact, the setting is updated in the database (check it with:

```
 SELECT [SettingName]
      ,[SettingValue]
      ,[SettingIsSecure]
      ,[CreatedByUserID]
      ,[CreatedOnDate]
      ,[LastModifiedByUserID]
      ,[LastModifiedOnDate]
  FROM [DNN56].[dbo].[DNN_HostSettings]
  where
  [SettingName] = 'PasswordExpiryReminder'
```

) but in fact the web user interface always displays '7', despite the value stored in database.

Edited:

I did some further tests and came to realize that reading the value of the property PasswordExpiryReminder of PasswordConfig always returns 7!

```
int i = DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.PasswordConfig.PasswordExpiryReminder;
```

So I turned it into

```
int i = DotNetNuke.Entities.Controllers.HostController.Instance.GetInteger("PasswordExpiryReminder");
```

and this time it returned -1 (because I'm not using the overload supplying a default value).

Then I had a flash, turned to SSMS and copied the value of the column SettingName and pasted it in Visual Studio.

```
int i = DotNetNuke.Entities.Controllers.HostController.Instance.GetInteger("PasswordExpiryReminder ");
```

Notice the trailing space? And with this code the real number stored in the table is returned. Look someone has a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in DotNetNuke, I've reproduced it myself on my own website.

I've added this to Gemini as an issue http://support.dotnetnuke.com/issue/ViewIssue.aspx?id=19436&PROJID=2

I'm looking to see if I can come up with a work around as well.